# Why is Connection Pooling using excessive memory?

Tags: .net, sql-server-2008, c#-4.0

I have a situation where when using a [SqlDataReader](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.sqlclient.sqldatareader%28v=vs.100%29.aspx), I am consistently getting a System.OutOfMemory error when reading a 9k text field.  This is occurring in an MsTest test, and at least for the moment, is consistently occurring.

I am fairly certain that all SqlConnections, SqlDataReaders, and SqlCommands are wrapped in `using` blocks.  Specifying `System.Data.CommandBehavior.SequentialAccess` when executing the reader had no effect.

However, if I make call to `SqlConnection.ClearAllPools()` prior to opening the connections in the troublesome part of the test, the problem goes away.

Why would the connection pool be holding excessive memory?

**Edit: Here is the relevant portion of the stacktrace**

```
at System.Data.SqlClient.TdsParser.TryReadPlpUnicodeChars(Char[]& buff, Int32 offst, Int32 len, TdsParserStateObject stateObj, Int32& totalCharsRead)
at System.Data.SqlClient.TdsParser.TryReadSqlStringValue(SqlBuffer value, Byte type, Int32 length, Encoding encoding, Boolean isPlp, TdsParserStateObject stateObj)
at System.Data.SqlClient.TdsParser.TryReadSqlValue(SqlBuffer value, SqlMetaDataPriv md, Int32 length, TdsParserStateObject stateObj)
at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlDataReader.TryReadColumnInternal(Int32 i, Boolean readHeaderOnly)
at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlDataReader.TryReadColumn(Int32 i, Boolean setTimeout, Boolean allowPartiallyReadColumn)
at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlDataReader.GetValueInternal(Int32 i)
at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlDataReader.GetValue(Int32 i)
at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlDataReader.get_Item(Int32 i)
```

Comment: There's a special performance counter NumberOfReclaimedConnections that you can use to see if you're properly releasing connections. See http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms254503.aspx

Comment: I added the following performance counters: NumberOfActiveConnections, NumberOfFreeConnections, NumberOfInactiveConnectionPools, NumberOfNonPooledConnections, NumberOfPooledConnections, NumberOfReclaimedConnections, NumberOfStasisConnections.  The only one that ever registered in perfmon above the 0 mark was "NumberOfInactiveConnectionPools"

Answer (score 1):

You're probably hitting the [large object heap](https://www.simple-talk.com/dotnet/.net-framework/the-dangers-of-the-large-object-heap/), such that individual records are either not collected or the heap is not properly compacted (defragmented), such that you're application's *address space* (not physical memory) becomes full (mostly full of holes) and you are not longer able to allocated new memory.

Comment: If that's the case, why would SqlConnection.ClearAllPools help?